# using delayMicroseconds inside interrupt

Tags: c++, arduino

i am just wondering if is there a better way to use interrupt and delay.
I am using 5 interrupts and i am not sure, if i should another way to "wait" for fireeing the Pin after 10us
The function i need is to ketch HALF waives of 50Hz AC power to change the Speed of the Motor. So each half waive is 10ms long, so now i want to change the speed in seting the PIN HIGH for a time 100us x dimming factor*

```
void ISR_0() //Interrupt D2
{PULSEcounter[0]++;}
void ISR_1() //Interrupt D3
{PULSEcounter[1]++;}
void ISR_2() //Interrupt D21
{PULSEcounter[2]++;}
void ISR_3() //Interrupt D20
{PULSEcounter[3]++;}
void ISR_4() //Interrupt D19
{// Firing angle calculation : 1 full 50Hz wave =1/50=20ms 
  // Every zerocrossing thus: (50Hz)-> 10ms (1/2 Cycle) 
  // 10ms=10000us
  // (10000us - 10us) / 100 = 100 (Approx)

  int dimtime = (100*dimming);    // For 50Hz =>100 when 0-100  
  delayMicroseconds(dimtime);    // Wait till firing the TRIAC
  digitalWrite(AC_LOAD, HIGH);   // Fire the TRIAC
  delayMicroseconds(10);         // triac On propogation delay (for 60Hz use 8.33)
  digitalWrite(AC_LOAD, LOW);    // No longer trigger the TRIAC (the     next zero crossing will swith it off) TRIAC}
void ISR_5() //Interrupt D18 
{PULSEcounter[5]++;}
```

the 1st answer was to add a timer:

```
void ISR_4() //Interrupt D19
{// Firing angle calculation : 1 full 50Hz wave =1/50=20ms 
  // Every zerocrossing thus: (50Hz)-> 10ms (1/2 Cycle) 
  // 10ms=10000us
  // (10000us - 10us) / 100 = 100 (Approx)

  int dimtime = (10000-100*dimming);    // For 50Hz =>100 when 0-100  
  if (micros() > dimtime) // Wait till firing the TRIAC
    digitalWrite(AC_LOAD, HIGH);   // Fire the TRIAC
    if (micros() > dimtime+10) // triac On propogation delay 
  digitalWrite(AC_LOAD, LOW);    // No longer trigger the TRIAC (the     next zero crossing will swith it off) TRIAC}
dimtime = 0;
    }
```

like this?

or timer in the `void loop`???

Answer (score 2):

A delay should **never** be used inside an interrupt service routine.

In general, interrupts need to be processed as fast as possible to allow other interrupts to fire.

To change a pin after 10µs, you could start a timer.

Chances are that using a delay function inside an interrupt service routine wouldn't even work, because that function could be using a (timer) interrupt too.

**Update**:

> The function I need is to ketch HALF waives of 50Hz AC power to change
>   the Speed of the Motor. So each half waive is 10ms long, so now I want
>   to change the speed in setting the PIN HIGH for a time 100us dimming
>   factor

You probably need [Pulse-width modulation (PWM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) for this.

On Arduino this can be done with [`analogWrite()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogWrite). See [PWM on Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/PWM).

`analogWrite()` takes care of outputting the waves, so all you need to do to change the motor speed is call `analogWrite()` once.

**Update** (@PeterM's comment):

In this case I think it's best to start a timer (and eventually modify/update a volatile variable with the delay time). In the mean time, all other interrupts can be fired and handled. In the timer interrupt, the pin can then be set/reset.

---

Also keep in mind that the Arduino `digitalWrite` function is [rather slow](https://www.peterbeard.co/blog/post/why-is-arduino-digitalwrite-so-slow/) (it has to map the Arduino pin numbers to PORT/pin), so in your case it would be better to write to the PORT/pin directly. Depending on the clock speed, using `digitalWrite` could be taking a large part of that 10µs delay.

Some [interesting info about `delayMicroseconds()` combined with interrupts](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/84776/arduino-delaymicroseconds):

> On Arduino there are timed interrupts configured that most are unaware
>   of. When an interrupt is received during the execution of the
>   delayMicroseconds(), the timing of `delayMicroseconds()` will be wrong.
>   You can of course stop interrupts before calling `delayMicroseconds()`
>   and enable them afterwards, but that again does impact timing accuracy
>   by the duration of compiled code for enabling/disabling.

Comment: The OP seems to be feeding a TRIAC (as per the comments in the code) This is a device that needs to be triggered synchronously with the AC supply in order to effect the correct control.  So while PWM is effectively what he needs it still needs to be synced somehow (which is what he was trying with the delay in the IR)

Comment: you mean something like this:? `void ISR_4() //Interrupt D19
{
  // 10ms=10000us
  // (10000us - 10us) / 100 = 100 (Approx)
  int dimtime = (10000-100*dimming);    // For 50Hz =>100 when 0-100  
  if (micros() > dimtime) // Wait till firing the TRIAC
        digitalWrite(AC_LOAD, HIGH);   // Fire the TRIAC
    if (micros() > dimtime+10) // triac On propogation delay 
      digitalWrite(AC_LOAD, LOW);    // No longer trigger the TRIAC (the next zero crossing will swith it off) TRIAC}
    dimtime = 0;
        }`

Comment: @PeterM - Ah, yes indeed - I'll update the post. Thanks.

Comment: you mean timer in the void loop or in the interrupt?

Comment: @Max - I would start the timer from inside the interrupt (this shouldn't take that much cycles). Although it would be possible to set a variable and handle it in te `loop()`, but it could become less accurate. (and perhaps you don't even need a loop at all, if all goes via interrupts - maybe the mcu could even be put asleep)

Comment: @Danny_ds: please chek the update in my Question...this way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100861/discussion-between-max-and-danny-ds).